# NSXML Parser always calls the "parseErrorOccurred" delegate first

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsxmlparser, nsxml

I have the following code,

```
NSString *string = "Some value";
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
self.parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
self.parser.delegate = self;
[self.parser parse];
```

After I call "parse" method it immediately calls the delegate `parseErrorOccurred` and then calls delegate `parserDidEndDocument`.

I want only one method to be called.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That delegate method is called when there is a fatal error, so there is an issue with the XML you are parsing.

The method has an `NSError` parameter, and that should give you a clue as to what is wrong with the XML.

Answer (score 0):

You mean when an error occurs in parsing, you want only **parseErrorOccurred()** called and **parserDidEndDocument()** not called?

One possible solution: write **parser.abortParsing()** in **parseErrorEccurred()**. I'm not sure this would actually work, if it fails, try the solution below:

Use a flag in your class that wrap the parser. Set the flag to true in **parseErrorEccurred()**, then check this flag in **parserDidEndDocument()** (if it's false then execute other code).

Hope this will solve your problem. :)